# if and concetenate if columns have X

Tags: excel-formula

I have to populate a column "Country Scope" and using this formula. However, I need to populate all the country name if it's there is a X in the column (column L thru Q). Country names should be populated with semicolon in between. See the pic.

[image]

```
=IF(L3="X","Corporate;",IF(M3="x","Mexico;",IF(N3="x","Argentina;",IF(O3="X","Dubai;",IF(P3="X","Broken Arrow;",IF(Q="X","Brazil;"))))))
```

I tried following code from https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/553169-concatenate-row-variable-number-columns.html but receiving Type mismatch error. I replace each column's x to respected country name.

```
Sub ConCatFromColumnC()
  Dim X As Long, LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, Delimiter As String
  Const StartRow As Long = 1
  Delimiter = vbLf
  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  For X = StartRow To LastRow
    LastCol = Cells(X, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If LastCol = 3 Then
      Cells(X, "B").Value = Cells(X, "C").Value
    Else
      Cells(X, "B").Value = Join(Application.Index(Range(Cells(X, "C"), Cells(X, LastCol)).Value, 1, 0), Delimiter)
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What Excel do you have?

Comment: it's excel 2013

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the following is working now.

```
Sub ConCatFromColumnC()
  Dim X As Long, LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, Delimiter As String
  Const StartRow As Long = 2
  Delimiter = vbLf
  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  For X = StartRow To LastRow
    'LastCol = Cells(X, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LastCol = 17
    If LastCol = 12 Then
      Cells(X, "K").Value = Cells(X, "L").Value
    Else
      Cells(X, "K").Value = Join(Application.Index(Range(Cells(X, "L"), Cells(X, LastCol)).Value, 1, 0), Delimiter)
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```